# Subversion Edge not installing "CollabNet Subversion Server" service

Tags: windows-10, installation, svn

I  have been successfully using Subversion Edge on my Windows 10 Pro system for years. A few days ago, I started to experience weird issues and I decided to reinstall the software.

I uninstalled it from the Programs applet, rebooted, then installed the software using the latest version (**CollabNetSubversionEdge-5.2.4_setup-x86_64_0.exe**).

The installation was successful in that no errors were reported and the installer seemed happy.

I was able to connect to the Subversion Edge interface (http://localhost:3343/csvn/). I clicked the green **Start** button, but was told that there was a problem starting the Subversion server.

The error message that I am seeing is:

**AH00436: No installed service named CollabNet Subversion Server**

Indeed, if I open the Services applet, I only see one CollabNet service:
CollabNet Subversion Edge (CSVNConsole). The other service was not installed.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, with reboots in between, with no luck. The server service refuses to install.

I have even tried deleting associated registry entries as well as all directories in **C:\csvn** (*except for my repositories directory*). No luck.

Does anybody have any ideas or clues that can lead me to resolve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: I have also tried repairing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled this version and installed the previous version 5.15 in 32 bits. The software is now working.

This is perhaps not a universal solution, but this workaround permits me to continue working, and I do not wish to spend any more time debugging the latest version, so I am closing this question.